# Port setting not used in my.cnf

Tags: xtrabackup

I'm trying to store the credentials for the Percona XtraBackup tool in the `/etc/my.cnf` file as follows:

```
[xtrabackup]
target-dir=/backup
user=root
password=[password]
host=[local ip]
port=12345
```

When running:

```
extrabackup --backup /backup
```

I get:

> Connecting to MySQL server host: [local ip], user: root, password: set, port: 3306

Everything is used except for the `port` which is ignored. What am I missing here? If I run `extrabackup --backup /backup --port=12345` it does work as expected.

Comment: I was wondering why the downvote, I guess another troll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as soon as I moved the file from `/etc/my.cnf` to `/root/.my.cnf` it started working.